# Does CXF integrates with CDI/Weld?

Tags: java, jax-ws, tomcat7

I’m currently working on a project using Tomcat 7 + CDI/Weld + Apache CXF. I would like to know if anyone around here have already integrated Apache CXF with CDI beans with success. I need to inject CDI beans on CXF endpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from version 3.0.0, CXF supports CDI 1.1 through cxf-integration-cdi module.

Maybe these links can help you:

http://aredko.blogspot.com.es/2014/05/apache-cxf-30-cdi-11-support-as.html

http://cxf.apache.org/docs/using-cxf-and-cdi-11-jsr-346.html